# C unix, asymmetric encryption on a socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, encryption

i have a client/server application in C unix, and i need to encrypt/decript the data with something like RSA (but not necessarly RSA). Is there a library (and the correspondent documentation) for this kind of function?

Comment: Uh... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security ?

Comment: They say OpenSSL could be useful for this kinda stuff.

Comment: @n.m. To borrow from Robot Chicken: *"They!?!  Who's **they**?!!"*  :)

Comment: Note: While my remark may have a joking tone, I actually do think that saying *"where do I download the secure codez"* is missing the point of what actual security involves.  Yes, OpenSSL is generally trusted but a bit of a maze codewise...if you want real security, you can't ignore the details.  You don't just link to a library and "get security".  :-/  If you can't understand the Wikipedia article you are no better off using the library than not.

Comment: I'd look at GnuTLS. IMO it has a bit nicer API than OpenSSL.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [SSL/TLS C API](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/ssl.html).

Answer (score 2):

For a Client/Server Application, the best way to ensure security is by using TLS/SSL.

The latest version of TLS is TLS 1.2 ([RFC 5246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt)) and as WagnerVaz has rightly mentioned, the best opensource library available fro TLS is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) .OpenSSL not only provides the library for TLS/Crypto. But, it also provides you a tool for generating certificates & private keys (based on RSA/DSA etc) on various formats.

Though OpenSSL is the finest TLS Library available in the market, it is a little difficult to understand and use for a first timer. There is a very wonderful tutorial written by Eric Rescorla himself on using OpenSSL.

[An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part - I)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part1.pdf) /
[An Introduction to OpenSSL Programming (Part - II)](http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part2.pdf)

It would be best if you first try to get some idea as to what is SSL and then start writing code for the same.

Alternately, let's say you are interested only in assymetric encryption / decryption, still OpenSSL's Crypto Libraries can be used.

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/Projects/lab01/reference/part1.pdf  and https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~srini/15-441/F02/Projects/lab01/reference/part2.pdf , better layout and newer than the html one